# Error in AdvancedWebView: void onUnhandledInputEvent

Tags: android, webview, signed-apk

I have found following warning while generation signed apk

> im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView$1: can't find referenced method  'void onUnhandledInputEvent(android.webkit.WebView,android.view.InputEvent)' in library class android.webkit.WebViewClient

I don't know what is this please help me to resolve this warning...

my layout file is..

```
<im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView
    android:id="@+id/about_us_description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
```

my java code is...

```
private AdvancedWebView aboutUs;
aboutUs = aboutUsDialogView.findViewById(R.id.about_us_description);
aboutUs.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
aboutUs.loadDataWithBaseURL("", content, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: post some code man

Comment: Also, that's not a warning: that's an error. Warnings can be ignored (but it's often a good idea not to), errors cannot. But please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue of *AdvancedWebView* coming up if you *targetSdkVersion* higher than *23*, where `onUnhandledInputEvent` was removed from Android SDK.

So, for now, you can solve it in two ways:

1) Set *target sdk 23* or lower

2) Import AdvancedWebView as a library. In the `onUnhandledInputEvent` method, there's a

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
```

condition. You need changing it to

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 23) {
```

or comment this method or just leave the body of this callback empty.

More info about the issue [here](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/issues/83)
Hope AdvancedWebView developers will fix this issue soon.